# Circumscribing Squares Around Closed Curves

Tags: geometry

I'm interested in solving the following problem (Problem 12-6 in "Introduction to Analysis" by Arthur Mattuck).

> Let $C$ be a continuous closed curve, i.e., one without endpoints. Show convincingly that it is always possible to circumscribe a square around $C$, that is, find a square all four of whose sides touch $C$ (so that the square cannot be shrunk without rotation to a smaller rectangle enclosing $C$). (Try some sketches).

**My attempt:**

I can't see how to start here as I'm not really clear on the problem. The use of "touch" makes me think of tangents, but then the curve $C$ is only said to be continuous. I'm also not sure about the meaning of "shrunk". Is there a clear interpretation of the problem which I can't see? I would also appreciate a hint on how to get started on this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the confusing mention of rectangle is to emphasize that we cannot move in one of the edges (without causing some points of the curve to end up outside the resulting rectangle).  This might be easy enough, but the problem of placing all four corners of a square on a very non-smooth curve is an open problem

Comment: I would think you want to find, given a vector in the first quadrant, a rectangle with all sides parallel or orthogonal to that vector. Then rotate the vector, and conclude that there is a satisfactory angle where the side lengths match up. Rather then "tangent," each edge would usually be called a supporting line.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming the problem takes place in $\Bbb{R}^2$.)

The first thing I would do is reject the closed curve $C$, and replace it with a compact set $C$. Any (continuous) curve $r : [0, 1] \to \Bbb{R}^2$ has a compact image, as it is the continuous image of a compact set.

Next, consider the function
$$f : \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R} : u \mapsto \sup_{c \in C} u \cdot c - \inf_{d \in C} u \cdot d = \sup_{c, d \in C} u \cdot (c - d).$$

Before I get into why I'm defining this function, I want to claim that it is continuous. Unfortunately, I don't have a particularly elementary proof in mind, but $f$ is a convex function as it is the pointwise supremum of a family of linear (and hence convex) functions $u \mapsto u \cdot (c - d)$, indexed by $(c, d) \in C^2$. This makes the function lower semicontinuous, and convex, and since we are in finite dimensions, this implies $f$ is continuous.

Now, I want to restrict $f$ to the unit circle $S_{\Bbb{R}^2}$, centred at $(0, 0)$. What does the function $f|_{S_{\Bbb{R}^2}}$ do? We start with a unit vector $u$, and fit two parallel lines, both perpendicular to $u$, to fit our set $C$ between as snugly as possible. The value of $f(u)$ is the distance between these two lines. Essentially, our problem reduces now to finding orthonormal vectors $e_1, e_2$ such that $f(e_1) = f(e_2)$, as the two lines perpendicular to $e_1$ and the two lines perpendicular to $e_2$ form a square which cannot be shrunk in the way the question describes.

Consider
$$g : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R} : \theta \mapsto f(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)).$$
Clearly, $g(\theta + 2\pi) = g(\theta)$ for all $\theta$. Further, note that, since $f$ is an even function, i.e. $f(-u) = f(u)$, we can refine this:
$$g(\theta + \pi) = g(\theta)$$
for all $\theta \in \Bbb{R}$. Now, $g$ is a continuous, periodic function. We can therefore adapt an argument [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2630285/problem-about-continuous-functions-and-the-intermediate-value-theorem); we should be able to find some $\alpha$ such that $g(\alpha) = g(\alpha + \pi/2)$. This is what we want! We can then take $e_1 = (\cos(\alpha), \sin(\alpha))$ and $e_2 = (\cos(\alpha + \pi/2), \sin(\alpha + \pi/2))$ to be our orthonormal vectors parallel to the sides of our minimal square.

To establish the existence of $\alpha$, consider the function $h(\theta) = g(\theta) - g(\theta + \pi/2)$. If $h(0) = 0$, then we are done: take $\alpha = 0$. Otherwise $h(0) > 0$ or $h(0) < 0$. If the former, then $h(\pi/2) < 0$, so by the IVT, $h(\alpha) = 0$ for some $\alpha$ between $0$ and $\pi/2$. Similar logic works when $h(0) < 0$, and hence $h(\pi/2) > 0$. Either way, we are done.

Hopefully someone comes up with a more elementary proof!

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the Intermediate Value Theorem. If $C$ is our closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, let $l$ and $l'$ be two parallel lines so that $C$ is contained inside the open strip between them (for example, you may choose $l$ and $l'$ parallel to the $x$-axis). Now, translate them parallel to their original positions until they touch $C$.

Now, repeat the process with two lines perpendicular to $l$ to obtain a rectangle $ABCD$ circumscribed about $C$. We will show that for a proper choice of slope of $l$ the rectangle becomes a square.

Indeed, let $f_{1}(l)$ denote the length of the side of the rectangle, say WLOG $AD$, parallel to $l$, and $f_{2}(l)$ denote the length of the side $AB$ perpendicular to $l$. Clearly the rectangle would be a square if $f_{1}(l)-f_{2}(l) = 0$.

Let $l^{*}$ be a line perpendicular to $l$. The corresponding rectangle circumscribing $C$ with sides parallel and perpendicular to $l^{*}$ is just the rectangle $ABCD$, but now the side $AD$ is perpendicular to $l^{*}$ and the side $AB$ is parallel to $l^{*}$. That is, $f_{1}(l^{*}) = f_{2}(l)$ and $f_{2}(l^{*})=f_{1}(l)$. Therefore,

$$f_{1}(l^{*})-f_{2}(l^{*}) = f_{2}(l)-f_{1}(l) = -(f_{1}(l)-f_{2}(l)).$$

Now, as we rotate $l$ until it is parallel to $l^{*}$, the circumscribed rectangle changes continuously. That is, the difference $f_{1}(l)-f_{2}(l)$ depends continuously on $l$. But then, rotating from $l$ to $l^{*}$ makes this difference change sign. Therefore, the Intermediate Value Theorem tells us that at some point (i.e. for a suitable slope of $l$) this difference must be $0$, and so the rectangle becomes a square, as desired.